# I want to move my slider by fetching images from database

Tags: php

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="active item">
        <?php 
        $latest_work=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from banners where status=1"); 
        while($latest_object= mysqli_fetch_object($latest_work)){
            ?>
            <img src="<?=WEBSITE_URL?>url/<?php if(isset($latest_object->image))echo $latest_object->image;?>"alt="Image" style="width:100%;height:500px;"> 
        </div>
        <div class="item "> 
            <?php 
        }
        ?> 
        <div> 
        </div>
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but your code looks messed up:

1. you should format it properly
2. you open a div before the while loop and then close it before opening another

   - this probably works, but makes it difficult to read later
3. the line for your image is properly messed up

try this:

```
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <?php 
        $latest_work=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from banners where status=1"); 
        // start a counter, at 1 to avoid confusion over 0 indexing
        $i = 1;
        while($latest_object= mysqli_fetch_object($latest_work)){

            // here, we have a counter, so that we can add the 'active' class to the first itteration
            if ($i == 1) {
                // we are the first itteration, so the calss should be 'item active'
                $class = 'item active';
            } else {
                // otherwise, its just 'item'
                $class = 'item';
            }
            // increment our counter $i
            $i++;
            if(isset($latest_object->image)) {
                $image = WEBSITE_URL . 'url/' . $latest_object->image

                echo '<div class="'.$class.'">';
                echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="Image" style="width:100%;height:500px;"> ';
                echo '<div>';

            } else {
                // do something else
            }

        }
        ?> 
</div>
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

form this point, your code should be readable, and then you can try to explain your problems